# How to remove points from the selected axis (Geometry Nodes)?

Tags: geometry-nodes, add-on

I have created a torus with Geometry Nodes using the [Erindale Toolkit](https://blendermarket.com/products/erintools) paid addon, and now I want to prevent duplicate points from forming at the seams of the torus. How can I remove points where the U and V axes are 0?

Comment: merge by distance?

Comment: @shmuel 
Well, that's the problem that I can't because it reduces my instance count

Comment: How did you create your torus? _Curve to Mesh_ ?

Comment: It is from the add-on https://blendermarket.com/products/erintools. There is a merge by distances in it but I have to remove it and now I want to remove the points in point 0 for U iV

Comment: Maybe asking on e.g. [Erindale's Discord channel](https://discord.gg/SHVDxCeH) will be a better idea? It's hard to figure out what you mean, considering how laconic your question is, and the mentioned product is behind a paywall. I have no idea why you would want to keep your instance count constant, or why it's being reduced by removing overlapping vertices…

Comment: I imagine the torus merges the vertices to provide a contiguous surface, having stashed UV coordinates on mesh face-corners, so the interpolation step from 1 to 0 works over the cyclic curves. Please clarify which instance-count you need to preserve. Present us with the actual problem you're looking to solve.

Answer (score 4):

If the radius is too small then that merge by distance will cause problems. What you can do instead is mute or delete that merge node and delete points where the U and V value is equal to 0.
[image: Screenshot of nodes]

This will delete that overlapping ring.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Generally, [questions regarding paid add-ons](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3043/) are not welcome here and are usually closed, but since you obviously make an effort to answer the questions arising from your node groups here, I thank you for the prompt reply!